# AWS Amplify Build Error - Mismatched Brackets Found In The Schema

Tags: yaml, aws-amplify, aws-codebuild

**End Desire:**

To build my AWS Amplify project in the `dev` environment, using full-stack CI/CD. So for example, pushing my changes to Code Commit will build the backend resources.

**Build Logs:**

```
2023-01-06T06:19:26.457Z [INFO]: [33mNote: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory[39m
2023-01-06T06:19:27.797Z [WARNING]: - Initializing your environment: dev
2023-01-06T06:19:29.164Z [WARNING]: - Building resource api/project
2023-01-06T06:19:33.756Z [WARNING]: - Building resource auth/project
2023-01-06T06:19:33.902Z [WARNING]: - Building resource storage/project
2023-01-06T06:19:33.939Z [WARNING]: ✔ Initialized provider successfully.
2023-01-06T06:19:34.452Z [WARNING]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2023-01-06T06:19:34.453Z [INFO]:  Syntax Error: mismatched brackets found in the schema. Unexpected ) at line 239 in the schema.
2023-01-06T06:19:34.453Z [INFO]: Learn more at: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/
```

**buildspec.yml:**

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm i
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

**Checks:**

1. I have checked the `graphql.schema` for errors.
2. I have removed the testing section in the buildspec.
3. I have added `amplify push --simple` as recommended [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html)
4. I've ran `npm run build` on my local CLI successfully

Comment: I had a similar issue today after updating amplify in a old project. I solved it by removing all comments in my graphql schema models. For some reason the amplfiy cli on the new version wasn't able to remove the comments when it was running a push. One of the comment had curly brackets, and it was that the compiler complained about

Comment: Could you write this in more detail as an answer, specifying how to get to the comments, and how to remove the commends? I'm sure it'll help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AWS Amplify console, under build settings, the AWS CLI version was "latest". Changing the AWS CLI version to `10.4.0` fixed the issue.

View AWS CLI Versioning here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/cli?activeTab=versions

Rather than going to `10.4.0`, go back a couple versions from the latest AWS CLI version at the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/1143). Amplify did (accidentally) parse GraphQL comments that contain actual queries, mutations and types and reported these as syntax error.

It has been fixed in v10.6.2 according to the GitHub issue.